# How to create makefile for compiling multiple programs

Tags: makefile, gcc, c

I have some problems with creating makefile. I have tried to compile some files from terminal and found right options for gcc to do this. 
But I have some troubles with creating one makefile to do all this tasks.

Here are my commands that work.

```
gcc -c pstree.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
gcc -o hello pstree.o -L/usr/lib/ -ltinfo

gcc -c fuser.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
gcc -c -o libsignals.a signals.c
gcc -o hello fuser.o -L/usr/lib/ -L. -lsignals

gcc -c -o libsignals.a signals.c
gcc -o hello killall.o -L/usr/lib/ -L. -lsignals
gcc -c killall.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
```

How can I make a Makefile for executing these commands?

Comment: what do you understand about making files? do you understand targets, dependencies, and linking? if not read up on those first.

Comment: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/ is a good source to help. also what is the problem in more specifics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
killall: hello\ fuser.o
    gcc -c -o libsignals.a signals.c
    gcc -o hello killall.o -L/usr/lib/ -L. -lsignals
    gcc -c killall.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.


fuser: hello\ pstree.o
    gcc -c fuser.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
    gcc -c -o libsignals.a signals.c
    gcc -o hello\ fuser.o -L/usr/lib/ -L. -lsignals

pstree: 
    gcc -c pstree.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
    gcc  -o hello\ pstree.o -L/usr/lib/ -ltinfo

clean:
rm -rf *.o
```

I wrote very very dirty you can define cc variable such as:

`CC = gcc`

`CFLAGS = -g -Wall -I.`

`LIBS = -L/usr/lib/ -lsignals`

 and so on..... 
Mine is very dirty ....

**NOTE:** Before each line of intending you **have to** use TAB, not space.

**usage :**

```
make clean
make killall
```